# I wonder why `std::unique_ptr<int> foo (new int)' is legal since `std::unique_ptr<int>` requires the input argument type should be `int`?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I wonder why `std::unique_ptr<int> foo (new int)`  is legal.

**What confused me is that I think the input argument type should be `int` in `std::unique_ptr<int>`, but the type `new int` is `int*`.**

I am a novice in C++. I thought it over and over but I still could not get the idea.
Could anybody make it clear for me? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually `std::unique_ptr` has [several constructor overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) one of which is

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
```

> Constructs a `std::unique_ptr` which owns `p`, initializing the stored pointer with `p` and value-initializing the stored deleter. Requires that Deleter is DefaultConstructible and that construction does not throw an exception.

It would not make sense to accept a value to `std::unique_ptr` since the purpose of that class is literally to manage a pointer. Instead it makes sense to accept a value to [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) which will construct a new object using that value.

Comment: I still think `std::unique_ptr<int>` requires the input argument type should be `int`, not `int*`.Where goes wrong?

Comment: @sunshilong369 `std::make_unique` takes values in it's arguments, the `std::unique_ptr` constructor takes pointers

Comment: @Alan Birtles I am a novice in C++.I could not see there is a `std::make_unique` in `std::unique_ptr<int> foo (new int)` indeed.Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @sunshilong369 For example `std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(5);`

Comment: @CoryKramer & Alan Birtles Yea,I could understand `std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(5);`.I think it's right.But i could not comprehend `std::unique_ptr<int> foo (new int)`.What confused me is that `new int` is the type of `int*`, not `int`.